# Double Progress Dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

G'day,
I've got a (Spinner) Progress Dialog showing in my Android code, but it seems to have a background dialog, as you can see in this picture:
[image: Two dialogs showing instead of one]

(Don't worry about the black box/gradient, it was closing by the time ddms caught it)
The code used to open it is:

`loading = new ProgressDialog(this,ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

loading.setMax(1);

loading.setTitle("Loading...");

loading.setMessage("Getting posts...\nThis may take a while depending on your internet connection.");

loading.setCancelable(false);

loading.setIndeterminate(false);

// ...

loading.setProgress(0);

loading.show();`

Is there something I'm doing wrong or something I can do to stop that happening?
Cheers.

Comment: style spinner ? have you tried without tht style